# Disabling the dayclick for the past dates in fullcalendar not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
inputDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var moment2 = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
if (date <= moment2) 
{
return false;

}

$('#datepicker2').val(inputDate);
$('#meeting').modal();

},
```

The above code disables dayclick the past dates and  **the current date too**.
But i need the dayclick enabled on the current date.

Comment: `date < moment2` istead of `date <= moment2` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one.

```
dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view) {
    if (moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') === date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') || date.isAfter(moment())) {
        // This allows today and future date
    } else {
        // Else part is for past dates
    }

},
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Worked fine for me. How can we do this for current year ?

Comment: I use this code but I can select the day before today.how I can disable select for days before today?

Answer (score 0):

Use Less Than Operator. Rather than using Less Than Or Equal To.

```
if (date < moment2)
{
     return false;
}
```